# I am unable to insert data in database

Tags: android, sqlite

```
03-17 15:19:50.332: E/SQLiteDatabase(1565): Error inserting Password=xx User_name=xx 
03-17 15:19:50.332: E/SQLiteDatabase(1565): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table login has no column named Password: , 
while compiling: INSERT INTO login(Password,User_name) VALUES (?,?)
```

**My database code**

```
db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("MyDb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login(User_id integer primary key autoincrement, User_name VARCHAR, Password VARCHAR )");
```

this is amy dbhelper code
  ** Insert Data code**

```
public boolean InsertData(String Table_Name , ContentValues cv)
{
if(db.insert(Table_Name, null, cv) > 0)
{
return true ;
}
return false;
}
```

this is my activity where i am accessing the insert method which i have already built in dbhelper class, what kind of edition i should make ...

```
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
list = new ArrayList<login>();
//list= dbHelper.getUser();
user_name.setText(list.get(0).getUser_name());
password.setText(list.get(0).getPassword());



    }

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        User_name = user_name.getText().toString();
        Password = password.getText().toString();

        if (User_name.length() > 0 && Password.length() > 0)
        {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("User_name", User_name);
            cv.put("Password", Password);

                if (SavingOptions.equalsIgnoreCase("Insert")) 
                {
                    if (dbHelper.InsertData("login", cv)) 
                    {
                        //list = dbHelper.getUser();    
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    else 
                    {
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login not Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                } 

        }
        else 
        {
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Plz fill all indexes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There's no such column and little details about what you did... Chances are that you've edited the table schema and there's an older version of the database file around. Uninstall the app to remove it.

Comment: There might be possible that the Password is the reserved keyword by the sqlite3. try to change column name and also increment version by 1 after change no need to uninstall.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

**db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login(_id integer primary key autoincrement, User_name TEXT, Password TEXT )");**

Comment: Doesn't affect anything since if a column spec has `CHAR`in it, such as `VARCHAR`, it gets the `TEXT` affinity anyway.

Comment: have yo changed the User_Id to _id ?

Comment: Provide your insert statement.

Answer (score -2):

**Password:**

 **:**   get it

 remove colon for the column entry

**EDIT**

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = instance.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues and add column-value pairs
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(USER_NAME, getUserName()); // get name
    values.put(PASSWORD, getPassword()); // get password

    // 3. insert
    db.insert(DBTABLE, // table
        null, // nullColumnHack
        values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

    // 4. close
    db.close();
```

Use this pattern for inserting values which is better and takes care of sql injection
As is noticeable, you are storing **passwords**

Comment: can you post your **insert** statement

Comment: The SQL in the exception doesn't have the `:`, it's part of the exception message

Comment: once again --> can you post your **insert** statement

Comment: The SQL is visible in the "while compiling" part of the exception.

Comment: //***** insert statement****

Comment: public boolean InsertData(String Table_Name , ContentValues cv)
{
 if(db.insert(Table_Name, null, cv) > 0)
 {
  return true ;
 }
 return false;
}